# Maximum number of code words

Tags: combinatorics, field-theory, coding-theory

I've been studying coding theory recently and most of the books I've looked at have had questions of the following type, but I haven't found any with a worked example:

*Let C be a ternary code of block length 8
that can correct all single errors. Show that C cannot contain more
than 25 code words.*

I haven't been able to get my head around how to approach a question like this, other than to start with the fact that the minimum distance must be d>2. So there is a zero word, and the next word is of weight 3. But as for enumerating them, I feel a bit lost. I'm sure it comes down to basic combinatorics, but I just can't see it. Could anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: How close is your question to those from the textbooks. Since the codewords will  be a subspace vectors, from a finite vector space, it is first possible to see what the max number could be without talking about the error correcting capability. If you want this number to be more precise then you can use any additional information. It would be easier to answer if your question was precise.

Comment: Ok, first I'm rather sure that there is a code with more than $25$ words in your case... Second, there are many bounds that you could apply, e.g. singleton bound, sphere packing bound, anticode bound,... depending on what kind of code you have. Your example (if the numbers would be correct) would most likely work best with singleton bound.

Comment: I've included the question verbatim. I've no other information but I can find a similar question with different numbers, on the off chance that the text book has an error in it?

Comment: But I found a code with $198$ code words just by searching for them.

Comment: @Chris: Are you familiar with the bounds I mentioned? If not, you should consider to study the sphere packing bound, as it is the most general. If you are interested in linear codes, then also the singleton bound can be very useful.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll just assume my difficulties were down to a typo. Thanks for that. And @Bemte, I was not before now and so I'll take a look at them for the benefit of any future problems. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily construct more code words than that. For example consider the modulo $3$ sums

$$\sigma_0 = \sum s_j$$
$$\sigma_1 = \sum_{0,2,4,6}s_j$$
$$\sigma_2 = \sum_{0,1,4,5}s_j$$
$$\sigma_3 = \sum_{0,1,2,3}s_j$$

If you alter one ternit of $s_j$ you would alter $\sigma_0$ and also by the alteration of the other sums you could determine which ternit that was changed and the amount of change.

If you require the sums to all be zero you would get $81$ valid code words, and introducing an error on any of those you can by checking those sums identify which ternit that is wrong and correct it.